# INNER JOIN block user and then friends table to remove user

Tags: php, mysqli, inner-join

I know that PHP can become quite complex when using INNER JOIN. I've had a play around with a few ideas and nothing seems to be working.

So this is what I'm working towards
When user A Blocks user B user B gets removed from their friends.

So I have this and have an error

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user1_id=15 AND user2_id=3 AND status=1
INNER JOIN friends ON block. 
DELETE fro' at line 1*

Could anyone explain inner join in full and show me where I've gone wrong for future usage.

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO block user1_id=$user1_id AND user2_id=$user2 AND status=1
INNER JOIN friends ON block. 
DELETE from friends where user1_id=$user1_id AND user2_id=$user2 AND status=2 ")
or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: Why are you using an `INNER JOIN` on an insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***should*** use two different statements and you ***have*** to use parameterized queries.

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO block (user1_id, user2_id, status) values (?,?,1)";    
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_insert);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user1_id);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user2_id);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

$sql_delete = "DELETE FROM friends where user1_id=? AND user2_id=? AND status=2 "
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_delete);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user1_id);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user2_id);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for being very useful and very helpful and not shooting me down. It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is all sorts of messed up. (This is not PHP's fault).

Please please please take a look at [MySQL INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) and [MySQL DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) syntax. I also don't understand your `INNER JOIN` on the `INSERT` statement.
MySQLi also only lets you execute 1 command per query (something about safety, and good design?)

`INSERT` should look like this (I don't know your table structures, so I'm assuming here somewhat:

```
INSERT INTO block (user1_id, user2_id, status) VALUES ('$user1_id', '$_user2_id', 1)
```

Apart from this, your DELETE query looks fine. Just make sure it's in it's own `mysqli_query()`.